STM32F401 Debouncing using registers
I want to debounce my input, using registers, but I'm running into the issue of it "not working" I am surely missing something in the logic I am overlooking.
Here is my interrupt:
void Interrupt_Init(void){
    EXTI15_10_Init();
    NVIC->IP[EXTI15_10_IRQn] =  (1 << 4);
    NVIC->ISER[40 >> 5] |= (1 << (40 % 32));
}

union InterruptFlag {
    struct {
       volatile bool flag: 1; // Just one bit for our flag
       volatile bool press: 1;
    } bits_access;
    uint32_t reg; // We'll use this for byte access
};
volatile union InterruptFlag flag = { .bits_access.flag = 0 }; // Initialize to 0
volatile uint16_t pressTime;
volatile bool lastButtonPress=0;
volatile bool buttonPress=1;

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){
flag.bits_access.flag = !flag.bits_access.flag;
EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt

}

and here's the debounce:
bool debounceButton(){
      TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
    if((GPIOC->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID13)!=lastButtonPress){
                  if(GPIOC->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID13){
                     pressTime=TIM3->CNT;

                  }else{
                      if(pressTime>10){
                          flag.bits_access.press=1;
                          return 1;
                      }
                  }
                  lastButtonPress=GPIOC->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID13;
              }
    return 0;
}

and this is what happens in the main function:
while (1)
  {

      int x;
          for(x=0; x<500; x++)
          {
              if(debounceButton()== 1){
                        x=x-1;
                        TIM2->CCR1=x;
                  }
              else{
                        TIM2->CCR1=x;
                        delayTRIP(1);
              }}

          for(x=500; x>0; x--)
          {
              if(debounceButton()== 1){
                          x=x+1;
                          TIM2->CCR1=x;
                              }
              else{
                          TIM2->CCR1=x;
                          delayTRIP(1);
          }

      }
  }}

I tried messing with the logic in the debounce but to no avail.

Do not use EXTI for buttons. Use timer interrupt (for example systick). It is the correct way. Imagine if you have to detect click, long click and double click. Good lunch with this logic. Also I would suggest using RTOS. Imagine i

@gulpr my task is NOT to use FreeRTOS, I'll see what I can do with that, do you got some resources on those timer interrupts? I'm off my laptop for the day

There are many ways to debounce buttons, but my favorite is The Ultimate Debouncer. It's also very simple to understand and implement.

I see absolutely no use/relevance for an RTOS here. EXTI is OK for a button when you need to know IMMEDIATELY that it changed state but you need to be careful how you handle that / configure that as any bouncing could cause a minor interrupt storm and confuse things. Generally just polling in a (systick) timer-based loop called from main is good enough, the standard 1ms SysTick gives you a fine enough grain to measure how long the button has been pressed / not pressed, you can do it much slower (EG 10ms) and just count up to a certain number / reset the count if the button bounces.
